# How to insert space after each three uppercase characters?

Tags: string, typescript

How can I transform the following string `ABCTest` into `ABC Test` using `string.replace()`?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: ```/[A-Z]{3}/g```?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just edited the question

Comment: If you don't want spaces between the three capital letters, why are there spaces between the three matches of a single capital letter each?

Comment: Try this - `value.replace(/([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{3})/ig, '$1 $2').trim()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
const updatedString = sourceString.replace(/[A-Z]{3}/g, match => match + ' ')
```